# Is it possible to put a psmatrix inside a table?

Tags: tables, pstricks, psmatrix

I wanted to create a table in which one column is a diagram that uses psmatrix, and the other column is text. I got the following error:

"Forbidden control sequence found while scanning use of \psmatrix.".

Here is a MWE that gives this error, where only the column with the psmatrix is shown:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf,pstricks,pst-node,array}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c}
  \begin{psmatrix}
    A & B & C  \\
    1 & 2 & 3
  \end{psmatrix}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

One solution is to drop the table altogether and use only a psmatrix, and put the additional text in a matrix column. But, logically it is more convenient to keep the matrix separate from the text, since in the real document the matrix is generated by macros.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add braces around the `pspicture`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf,pstricks,pst-node} 
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c}
  {\begin{psmatrix}
    A & B & C  \\
    1 & 2 & 3
  \end{psmatrix}}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The `&` at the top level are confusing TeX's table parser.

Answer (score 3):

use a different syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf,pst-node} 
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c}
  \psmatrix
    A & B & C  \\
    1 & 2 & 3
  \endpsmatrix
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```